# Samba: does current linux client support asynchronous reads?

Tags: linux, asynchronous, samba, cifs

In the interest of increasing performance, is it possible to read asynchronously from a CIFS mounted file, on linux?

Thanks!!!

Comment: Asychronous is not synonymous with higher performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Glibc's aio implementation creates threads to do the I/O, so it does not depend on the filesystem type to work. (On the other hand, that also means you can create your own threads instead, without missing out on much.)